# Searching for prezi like software that supports LaTeX natively

Tags: software, presentation, specific-software

I've been making some mathematical presentation in prezi, for example: [Spectral Theorem (from proofs of the book)](https://prezi.com/aexypzd25tmd/spectral-theorem-from-proofs-of-the-book/).

This is a prezi that I presented today, but it took me a hell lot of work, to get LaTeX working in prezi. I was wondering if there are any prezi alternatives that are more LaTeX friendly?

I'm a programmer myself, so if they don't exist, I may try to make one myself some day, but I want to make sure that I don't miss out on some great already existing software.

Comment: Are you sure you want to ask this at math educators? http://tex.stackexchange.com/ might be more appropriate.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Many times questions like these get closed on tex.stackexchange, because it is not really about the TeX language itself.

Comment: i have never seen any software like this before but i may be wrong..

Comment: @Kasper, I just wanted to make sure you didn't ask it here by accident. I'm not that familiar with tex.SE (or other non-math SE sites) myself, so I can't tell if some other site would be better. But the question is interesting.

Comment: Maybe instead you should request Latex support from the Prezi prople...

Comment: @GeraldEdgar I've asked for that 3 years ago... and many others have asked, but I'm giving up hope...

Answer (score 4):

Not aware of any software but here's a simple hack to achieve what you want:

1. Go to [codecogs equation editor](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php).
2. Write your LaTeX equation.
3. Copy the url generated (it will be exported as swf).
4. In import dialog box in Prezi, enter the url
5. Voila!

Someone has written a detailed blog post about it [here](https://dawes.wordpress.com/2011/11/06/latex-in-prezi/).